# Pip list command outputs nothing

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to get the list of installed packages from command prompt.

Pip works fine: it installs / uninstalls packages and even shows information about a specific package with the `pip show package_name` command.

But for the `pip list` command, it outputs nothing: not even an error, just an empty string.

Comment: Did you try `pip freeze`? Are you in a virtual environment?

Comment: I am looking for a way to view the list of installed packages. Pip freeze, also shows nothing.

Comment: `pip freeze` will show the list of installed packages just in a different format

Comment: I see, but is also does not output anything.

Comment: Try cmd in run as admin mode and then command

Comment: Also tried, same result.

Answer (score 0):

When you press enter after typing `pip list` in cmd, it takes some time to display. It depends on your system's performance. Don't close the window, just wait for it to display

Comment: Yes, it takes about a second to display, but it displays an empty string, not a list.

Comment: Is it showing new line like C:\Users\> or just empty?

Comment: May be you are using old versions of pip. Type 'pip help' to see the syntax for showing list

Comment: I am using the oldest version of pip (19.3.1).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add py -m before.

Try:
$py -m pip list

Answer (score -1):

py -m pip list 'this solves the problem you probably have several version of python installed'

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34541574)