# pip list command returns an empty string

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I recently updated my python version from 3.9.6 to 3.10.2, and now I can not get pip to work properly. Specifically `pip list` and `pip freeze` as they do not output any of the modules that I imported. Example shown below.

[image: pip not working]

So far I have tried restarting my computer, trying in a virtual environment, running cmd prompt as admin, and trying it in Visual Studio Code. Not sure what to do next.

I did notice however that this is possibly a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58768663/pip-list-command-outputs-nothing), but no answer was provided on that post either.

Comment: Can you share the output of `pip --version`? You can redact your username from the path it outputs if you wish

Comment: @shriakhilc 
`pip 22.0.2 from Python310\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.10)`

Comment: I have found that some other people have had issue with 22.0.2 and upgrading to it. They have experienced lost features. They direct to this link: https://www.programmersought.com/article/74769597727/

Comment: @EliHarold
I uninstalled setuptools with `python -m pip uninstall pip setuptools` from the link you provided, and I had to reinstall it with [ensurepip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/#ensurepip).

I am still met with the same blank output with `pip list` and `pip freeze`, but I am now using `pip 21.2.4 from Python310\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.10)`

Comment: I might just try uninstalling Python entirely and re-installing it

Comment: @GuhBean yeah im lost at this point I am on 21.3.1 and it works perfectly in both visual studio code and cmd